# how can i lookup values between two sets by avoiding duplicates if any

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For eg, Sheet1 has a table with A,B,C as rows with respective amounts against them.
Sheet2 has another table with A,B,A,C,B in rows.

Now how can I lookup Sheet2 with Sheet1 without duplicates

how can i lookup values between two sets by avoiding duplicates if any.

Comment: Use `XLOOKUP()` with `UNIQUE()` function. Post few sample data with desired output for further clarification.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To return non-duplicate values between column A in Sheet1 and Sheet2 you can use `=UNIQUE(TOCOL(Sheet1:Sheet2!A:A,1),,1)`